# I keep getting a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on input of 5 6

Tags: java

I keep getting a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on input of:
5 6

Please assume that I am entering only two numbers in line with a space between them

Tried both `next()` and `nextLine()`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
         String NandK=in.nextLine();
        String[] pow=NandK.split("\\s+");
        
        String valueOfN=pow[0];
        String valueOfK=pow[1];
        System.out.println(valueOfN);
        System.out.println(valueOfK);
        
     }
}
```

Output

> Hello World
>
> 5 6
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>
> at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:13)

Comment: code works fine! Got the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it will be not fixed how many char you will by giving in input it is better to use for loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String NandK = in.nextLine();
    String[] pow = NandK.split("\\s+");

    for(int i = 0;i<pow.length;i++){
        String valueOfN = pow[i];
        System.out.println(valueOfN);

    }
```

Comment: Please assume that I am entering only two numbers in line with a space between them

Comment: @MukundPradeep it will print both of them as of your output.

Comment: I need to use one of them later

Comment: @MukundPradeep then u need to add logic for it.

Comment: your snippet worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong regex

Use `"\\s+"` instead of `"//s+"`

and use `in.nextLine()` instead of `in.next()`

Output

```
Hello World
5 6
5
6
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: Still gives the exception

Comment: Bit I am not getting any exception.. check my answer properly

Comment: Tried the same. Still throwing exception. The exception occurs where i try to assign the value of pow[1] to valueOfK.

Comment: @Mukund Pradeep I added my output in answer.. check it

Comment: I cannot understand why it does not work for me